# PHP Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found after building PHP 5.6 from source

Tags: php, mysql

I've compiled php 5.6 from source
and got the following error at runtime because mysqli is not found

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in
```

I compiled with following configuration

```
./configure \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config\
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--prefix=/usr/local \
--with-layout=PHP \
--with-pear \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-gmp \
--enable-exif \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mhash \
--with-zlib \
--with-bz2 \
--enable-zip \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-iconv \
--enable-intl \
--with-icu-dir=/usr \
--with-gettext \
--with-pspell \
--enable-sockets \
--with-openssl \
--with-curl \
--with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-vpx-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-t1lib=/usr \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--enable-soap \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-xsl \
--with-readline \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-shmop \
```

I can't find mysqli.so in the lib directory:

```
[root@ns507257 php]# cd /usr/lib64/php/modules/
[root@ns507257 modules]# ll
total 3300
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   74648 Sep 30 05:47 curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2713352 Sep 30 05:47 fileinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   44680 Sep 30 05:47 json.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  116296 Sep 30 05:47 pdo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   29168 Sep 30 05:47 pdo_sqlite.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  271960 Sep 30 05:47 phar.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   51336 Sep 30 05:47 sqlite3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   58384 Sep 30 05:47 zip.so
```

php code

```
class DBUtil{
  public static function get($query,$dbinfo){
    //print_r($dbinfo);
    $host=$dbinfo['host'];
    $username=$dbinfo['username'];
    $password=$dbinfo['password'];
    $db=$dbinfo['db'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
      exit();
    }
    /* Select queries return a resultset */
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("$query")) {
      /* free result set */
      $result->close();
      return $result;
    }
  }
  }
```

In addition, it looks like my `/usr/local/lib64/` is empty.

what's wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the code as well? I could be a simple typographical mistake.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek: updated

Comment: Are you going to post the answer that you edited in and out of the question, or did you not solve this after all?

Comment: Is mysqli extension enabled in **php.ini** file ?

Comment: FWIW, I moved your answer into an answer - ideally, the question presents the problem as clearly as possible while solutions appear below.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, the previous PHP installation was not removed cleanly and this interfered with my build.

To correct this, I needed to do:

```
yum remove php-common
./configure
make install
```

Now, it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--prefix=/usr/local \
```

...means that the libs should be installed in /usr/local/lib64.php/modules, not /usr/lib64/php/modules

Comment: it looks like my  /usr/local/lib64/ is empty

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on my dev windows machine after upgrading PHP to 5.6.15.
Phpinfo() would say that mysqli was loaded.

However to resolve the issue I had to set "extension_dir" in php.ini to the full path of the extension folder.
Leaving this setting to "ext" would not work either.